# Escape Character Cannot Working in ReactJS Map Looping

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-escape-characters

I have file call **ArrayCustomer.js** contains ARRAY like this:

```
const ArrayCustomer = [
  {
    index:1,
    kondisi: 'Daftar Baru',
    badge: 'badge btn-warning',
  },
  {
    index:2,
    kondisi: 'Pelanggan dibawah 10m&lt;sup&gt;3&lt;/sup&gt;',
    badge: 'badge btn-secondary',
  },
]

export default ArrayCustomer
```

then I Import that **Array** to my Component call **EditCustomer.js** 
and in **form input** I loop use map for showing **kondisi** like this:

```
<FormGroup>
  <Label for="status">Status Pelanggan</Label>
  <Input
    required
    value={this.state.status}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    type="select"
    name="status"
    id="status"
  >
    ArrayCustomer.map(item => (
    <option value={item.index}>{item.kondisi}</option>) ) }
  </Input>
</FormGroup>;
```

but the Escape Character Does'nt showing as HTML/JSX Tag.
I Stack because of this, I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render HTML strings in React elements.

decode the HTML string with this function.

```
const decodeString = str => {
  var element = document.createElement("div");
  element.innerHTML = str;
  return element.childNodes.length === 0
    ? ""
    : String(element.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
};
```

Update `map` method, use the decodeString method while adding to element.

```
ArrayCustomer.map(item => (
  <option
    value={item.index}
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: decodeString(item.kondisi) }}
  ></option>
));
```

Comment: I tried and the result is ```<sup>3<sup>``` any proggress after I try your answer. but may you have another solution? @Sive Kondapi Venkata

Comment: @MuhammadAdamC, updated answer to have the `decodeString` method. With this should work.

Comment: thank you very much, using the ```decodeString``` method successfully:)